# how to get tweet id and gplus share id using GWT / javascript

Tags: javascript, gwt, twitter, google-plus

I am trying to integrate twitter,Google plus into my website, to share details in it. I was able to tweet and share post on twitter and gplus respectively but was unable to get tweet id and google plus share id. for twitter i used tweet even using Java script, response was null. Could you please help me in tracking the tweet id and gplus share id.

Twitter

```
<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

// Define our custom event handlers
function clickEventToAnalytics (intentEvent) {
    console.log("click"+ intentEvent.data);
    alert("inside clickEventToAnalytics"+intentEvent.data.source_tweet_id);
  if (!intentEvent) return;
  var label = intentEvent.region;
  pageTracker._trackEvent('twitter_web_intents', intentEvent.type, label);
}
 //to get tweet data
function tweetIntentToAnalytics (intentEvent) {
    console.log("tweet"+ intentEvent.data);
    alert("inside tweetIntentToAnalytics"+intentEvent.data.tweet_id);
    alert("inside tweetIntentToAnalytics"+intentEvent.id);  
  if (!intentEvent) return;
  var label = "tweet";
  pageTracker._trackEvent(
    'twitter_web_intents',
    intentEvent.type,
    label
  );
}



// Wait for the asynchronous resources to load
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
  // Now bind our custom intent events
  twttr.events.bind('click', clickEventToAnalytics);
  twttr.events.bind('tweet', tweetIntentToAnalytics);     
});</script>
//using twitter share button 
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="test" data-count="none" >Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

Comment: Please post whatever code you got and any errors you are running into

Comment: I have added code for twitter share .... Wehn i ran the above code ,once the control is back to browser, intentEvent.data.tweet_id is undefined , intentEvent.data also not provinding any value. Could you please comment on it.